# ncurses/diag like menu for console for OpenBSD?

Tags: console, openbsd, menu, ncurses

Strictly on the console, so no GUI, how can I create similar on OpenBSD, like as YAST uses for SLES?

[image]

Cannot find any ncurses or diag packages on OpenBSD ports.

Comment: OpenBSD has ncurses in its base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ls -d /usr/ports/*/dia*
/usr/ports/graphics/dia/   /usr/ports/misc/dialog/
$ cat /usr/ports/misc/dialog/pkg/DESCR
Dialog is typically invoked from a shell script to provide a set of
curses widgets, e.g. yes/no, checklists, input boxes, menus, progress
boxes, text boxes, etc.
$ doas pkg_add dialog
...
```

There are also more complicated package database searching tools such as `pkglocatedb` that may or may not require having the ports tree installed.

Comment: `pkg_info -Q dia` does the same thing with the packages.

Comment: except `pkg_info -d -Q dia` shows all sorts of hits and it would be easy to miss "dialog" in all that